# How to tell when a cocoa webview has updated

Tags: cocoa, webkit, webview

I have a cocoa webview hosted in an `NSWindow`. I'd like to be notified whenever the webview updates any content. I don't see a relevant cocoa api to allow me to do this. Ideally, I'd like to do this without having to modify webkit source, ie use existing cocoa api. I've tried using NSWindow's delegate to be notified whenever the `NSwindow` updates, but this doesn't cover all the webview updates.

On windows, where I modified webkit source, I had access to:

```
IWebUIDelegatePrivate2::WebViewPainted
```

Any ideas on what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

There is the WebResourceLoadDelegate protocol which lets you track loading content but I dont think that will help you with dhtml type updates.